# Isekai manwha. Main character's friend is being mind-controlled by a princess

Tags: story-identification, manga

This manwha started with a group of students getting teleported into another world. They are greeted by the king and the princess who tells them that they have to help them defeat a greater threat like a demon lord and that everyone now has magic powers.

The main character is suspicious about the king and the princess and then finds out that the princess is start to control one of his friends. When he breaks the control spell this character dies.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Is the character that dies one of the students? "Assassin de Aru Ore no Sutetasu ga Yuusha Yori mo Akiraka ni Tsuyoi Nodaga" has a princess controlling/cursing summoned students, and someone dies during the MC's investigation, but it's a resident of their world. And she's assassinated, rather than it being automatic.